# Minecraft command block teleportion runaway

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am trying to make a moving airship in vanilla 1.16.1 minecraft. Before, you could just use /clone to move the ship and then teleport the players, but now if you have the ship clone itself the command blocks in the cloned ship *also* clone themselves, leading to a runaway reaction where the ship moves until it exits render distance. That would be nice if I also didn't want to be able to control the ship.

I've tried using `/clone move`, which runs until it exits render distance, then I switch to having one command block with `/clone replace` and then a second command block with `/set air`, and that setup runs a few times before it finally stops, which is closer to what I want but still out of control. I can get the specific commands if you need them.

What is the current way to make a *controllable* moving command block structure?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I've tried using /clone move, which runs until it exits render distance, then I switch to having one command block with /clone replace and then a second command block with /set air, and that setup runs a few times before it finally stops, which is closer to what I want but still out of control. I can get the specific commands if you need them.

Comment: Can you edit your post so it says that?

Answer (score 1):

So after some finangling, I figured out that I should use `execute` to test whether the previous ship has been deleted to stop the runaway reaction, and I am going to post the commands I used so that anyone else suffering through this spaghetti will also be able to do this.

I used a chain of 3 command blocks with the following commands:

`/execute if block ~-6 ~-3 ~1 minecraft:air run clone ~-2 ~-9 ~-2 ~24 ~9 ~4 ~28 ~-9 ~-2 replace`

`/execute if block ~-6 ~-2 ~1 minecraft:air run execute as @a[distance=..25] at @s run tp @s ~30 ~ ~`

`/fill ~-6 ~-6 ~-2 ~-32 ~11 ~4 minecraft:air`

The coordinates in the execute statement is a block in the build that was easy to reach. I don't know if this will work with the `/clone move` command but I'm happy with just using the 3 command blocks and calling it a day.